# Stopping a particular ngGrid cell (not column) from being edited during ngGridEventStartCellEdit

Tags: ng-grid

I have an ngGrid with some individual cells (not columns) that I don't want to be edited. In my [example plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSK03HAfK1UWPOTLUzNN?p=preview) I want to not edit the  cells where the row and column index are the same.

I tried `preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagation()`, and an old fashioned `return false;` in my `ngGridEventStartCellEdit` but the cell still enters edit mode.

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventStartCellEdit', function (event) {
    var row = event.targetScope.row.rowIndex;
    var col = event.targetScope.col.index - 1;
    if (row == col) {
        console.log("Not Gonna propagate");
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The `console.log("Not Gonna propagate");` fires.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `cellEditableCondition` and putting your logic there ? See the [config documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using `cellEditableCondition`.

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SDMuz9an3bcdR7GsO4Bl?p=preview) with it. All you need is :

```
enableCellEdit: true,
cellEditableCondition: 'row.rowIndex !== col.index',
```

enableCellEdit has to be `true` for the editable condition to work.